# AutoMapper 3.1.1 and Entity Framework 6.1 Proxy objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I realized this has been asked already, but the solutions I've read don't seem to make a difference so far. I'm using Entity Framework 6.1 and AutoMapper 3.1.1. Taking the following objects: `Company` and `CompanyListItem`; I try this:

```
Mapper.Configure<Company, CompanyListItem>();
```

Well, when I try to do the actual mapping it crashed and burned with an exception that there's no mappings defined. I know this is caused because of the proxy objects created by Entity Framework. One solutions I've seen so far is to call an overloaded version of the Map method:

```
IQueryable<Company> companies = CompaniesService.FindCompanies();

Mapper.Map(companies, typeof(Company[]), typeof(CompanyListItem[]));
```

And it still doesn't work and yells at me.

I've also read other posts that this has been fixed as of 2.2.1? Is this different or did it regress? I'd appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using Automapper incorrectly, you need to use the [QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) namespace, so your code should be

```
IQueryable<Company> companies = CompaniesService.FindCompanies();

CompanyListItem[] results = companies.Project().To<CompanyListItem>().ToArray();
```

Also if you where going to do it the other way you still had `Mapper.Map` wrong, it should have been

```
IQueryable<Company> companies = CompaniesService.FindCompanies();

CompanyListItem[] result = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Company>,CompanyListItem[]>(companies);
```

but I still recommend doing the `.Project().To<T>()` method as it will perform the mapping server side instead of client side so you potentially have less data that needs to be sent over the wire.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I've only been "using" AutoMapper since last night, so there's gaps in my understanding of it. Thanks for the help.