# AutoMapper custom TypeConverter not working

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to integrate AutoMapper into my project and it's mostly working out, now that I know how to [project EntityFramework objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723133/automapper-3-1-1-and-entity-framework-6-1-proxy-objects), but I keep getting this exception: *Unable to create a map expression from System.Byte to System.Int32*. So, I figure I'll make a custom type converter and it will work, except it doesn't:

```
public sealed class ByteToInt32Converter : TypeConverter<byte, int> {
    protected override int ConvertCore(
        byte source) {
        return (int)source;
    }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<byte, int>().ConvertUsing<ByteToInt32Converter>();
```

Looking at the documentation and other search results, this should be correct, but I'm still getting an exception. What do?

**Update**

Per Scott's request, here's my source object, `Company`, and the destination object `SelectItem`:

```
public partial class Company {
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region Relationship Properties
    public byte? ParentCompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }
    public virtual Company ParentCompany { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    public Company() {
        this.Companies = new List<Company>();
        this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
        this.States = new List<State>();
    }
}

public sealed class SelectItem : ISelectItem {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public interface ISelectItem : IItem {
    string Key { get; set; }
    int Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IItem {
}
```

And here's the mapping code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Company, SelectItem>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Key,
        o => o.MapFrom(
            s => s.Name))
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Value,
        o => o.MapFrom(
            s => s.Id));
```

I'm basically trying to flatten the `Company` object down to a "key-value pair" object that I can pass into the MVC `Html.DropDownList()`. I didn't particularly care to match the types of the Key Id since I was only using it to generate the drop down list so I just left it all as `int`. Granted, I could try to be generic, pass in the key type, etc, but it just feels way too complicated for not much gain.

Pretty much all of the objects I would want to use as drop down list options, follow the same convention.

Comment: Yea... I should of mentioned that, when working with Queryable Extensions you can't use all of the possible options in `CreateMap`. Can you show a full listing of class you are coming from and the class you are going to from your `Project.To<T>()` statement, we can help you figure out what you would need to put in your `CreateMap`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I've updated my answer per your request.

Answer (score 1):

Try this converter

```
 public class ByteToInt32Converter : ITypeConverter<byte, int>
    {
        public int Convert(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return System.Convert.ToInt32(context.SourceValue);
        }
    }

Mapper.CreateMap<byte, int>().ConvertUsing<ByteToInt32Converter>();

// your Company to SelectItem mapping code.
```

Comment: That didn't work. What I suspect is the cause, which I think Scott is also suspecting, is that the converter itself is not the problem. In fact, I contend it work perfectly fine, BUT, AutoMapper is simply not invoking it as it should. Perhaps somehow the types don't match?

Comment: actually Alex, for byte to int, you shouldn't be needing an explicit converted at all. AutoMapper should not complain for it. can you please any custom converter code and try this: var si = Mapper.Map<Company, SelectItem>(company); let us know the exact invocation code which causes the exception.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that too, but nevertheless, it's yelling at me. That being said, `Company` is an Entity Framework proxy object, which may have something to do with it?