# AutoMapper throws Missing Map when Map exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

**Specifications:** .NET 4.5.1 - MVC 5.2.2 - EF 6.0 - AutoMapper 3.2.1

I was first having Proxy object error but was able to solve it by doing the following: [AutoMapper 3.1.1 and Entity Framework 6.1 Proxy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723133/automapper-3-1-1-and-entity-framework-6-1-proxy-objects)

Once I fixed that error, I instantly got the following error message:[image]

For some reason, it says the map from Pages to PagesViewModel doesn't exist, even though it does. Here is my code:

In **Global.asax.cs**:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     ConfigureAutomapper.Configure();
     ....
```

In **AutoMapper.cs (UPDATED)**

```
public static class ConfigureAutomapper
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        ConfigurePublications();
        ConfigureBlog();
        ConfigureBasic();
        ConfigureLists();
    }

    public static void ConfigurePublications()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<PublicationsMappings>();
        });
    }

    public static void ConfigureBlog()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<BlogMappings>();
        });
    }

    public static void ConfigureBasic()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<BasicMappings>();
        });
    }

    public static void ConfigureLists()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<ListMappings>();
        });
    }
}
```

...

```
public class BasicMappings : Profile
    {
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get
            {
                return "BasicMappings";
            }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Pages, PagesViewModel>();

            Mapper.CreateMap<PagesViewModel, Pages>();
            ...
```

I have traced it and it gets in there and creates the map. When it goes to use the conversion, it doesn't work.

For the model and viewModel, all the variable names are the same. I only added data annotations and some sanitize classes `set { pageDescription = value.StringSanitizer(); }`

The difference comes when declaring linked objects/tables:

**Model:**

```
public virtual PageType PageTypes { get; set; }
public virtual SiteMap SiteMap { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Rows> Row { get; set; }
public virtual Track Tracks { get; set; }
```

while my **ViewModel:**

```
public PageTypeViewModel PageTypes { get; set; }
public SiteMapViewModel SiteMap { get; set; }
public ICollection<RowsViewModel> Row { get; set; }
public TrackViewModel Tracks { get; set; }
```

Connects to the viewModels of those models. All of which are mapped in AutoMapper.cs

---

**UPDATE:**
I have a unit test already in the project:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AutoMapper_Basic_Configuration_IsValid()
{
      //Arrange

      //Act
      ConfigureAutomapper.ConfigureBasic();

      //Assert
      Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
 }
```

**It passed all the tests with no mapping errors.**

Can anyone give me some insight on this issue? Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `Mapper.CreateMap<Pages, PagesViewModel>();`, use `CreateMap<Pages, PagesViewModel>();`.

```
protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Pages, PagesViewModel>();

        CreateMap<PagesViewModel, Pages>();
     ...
```

Inside a profile, you need to refer to the instance of `Mapper` which is `this.CreateMap` or simply `CreateMap`.

**Update**
Updating my answer so that future readers don't have to wade thru the comments to figure out the issue.

The problem was with multiple calls to `Mapper.Initialize`. Each new call would clear out previous initialization. The fix was to have a single initialization call and add all profiles in there.

Comment: I first tried adding that and it still gave the same error. Then I tried replacing what I had with just `CreateMap<>();` and it still gave me the same error. I then replace all of the `Mapper.CreateMap<>();` with `CreateMap<>();` inside of that profile and it is still throwing the error.

Comment: Can you add `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` and see what it complains about? Might help in locating the issue.

Comment: Where should I add that?

Comment: In the Unit Tests project associated with your main project.

Comment: You can add it after your call to `ConfigureAutomapper.Configure();` - this way it'll validate all mappings.

Comment: I have updated my question. i had a unit test in there already. No errors were found.

Comment: Do you have any other `Mapper.Initialize` calls in your solution? Also, have you tried adding the maps directly in your App start w/o going via the profile - like calling `Mapper.CreateMap<Pages, PagesViewModel>();` in `Application_Start`? I suspect somethign is clearing away your profiles/initialization.

Comment: I do have more than one `Mapper.Initialize` calls. I have added them to the original question. I will try adding the maps directly in my App_Start without the profile and see how that goes.

Comment: There goes your problem! Each call to `Mapper.Initialize` will clear prior initialization. You need to have a single initialization call and add all profiles there.

Comment: That definitely solved theproblem. I'm going to mark your answer as Correct because you solved the question. Although I am still getting an error: **"Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state"**. Happens when I make the database call (the image I uploaded in the question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62003/discussion-between-mrchief-and-termato).

Comment: In my case, same entity was present 2 different databases and thats causing mismatch of mapping objects. Adding answer just in case anyone faced similar issue like me. wasted 4 hours searching that..

Answer (score 1):

There's probably something configured incorrectly.

You should add the following unit test

```
        [Test]
        public void AreMappingsValid()
        {
            ConfigureAutomapper.Configure();
            AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
```